# Why does booktitle not show up here?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

Why does booktitle not show up here? Is it normal?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibi.bib}
@inbook{Tarkoma, place={Cambridge}, title={Introduction}, DOI={10.1017/CBO9781107326279.002}, booktitle={Smartphone Energy Consumption: Modeling and Optimization}, publisher={Cambridge University Press}, author={Tarkoma, Sasu and Siekkinen, Matti and Lagerspetz, Eemil and Xiao, Yu}, year={2014}, pages={3–22}}
\end{filecontents*}
\newpage
%
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibi.bib}

\vspace{11pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf `@inbook` does not support a `booktitle` field (unlike say `@inproceedings`). Presumably the chapter title or chapter number goes into the `chapter` field and the overall book title into `title`.

Comment: @moewe I see. I'm curious where did you see that in the link?

Comment: ugh, sorry, wrong link. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf should be the one (page 5).

Comment: My impression is that for this item the correct type is `book`. The fact you're citing the introduction should be made clear at callout.

Comment: @egreg I changed from `inbook` to `book` but I don't see any changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@incollection`.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    
\begin{filecontents*}{bibi.bib}
    @incollection{Tarkoma,
        address={Cambridge}, 
        title={Introduction}, 
        DOI={10.1017/CBO9781107326279.002}, 
        booktitle={Smartphone Energy Consumption: Modeling and Optimization},
        publisher={Cambridge University Press}, 
        author={Sasu Tarkoma  and  Matti Siekkinen and Eemil Lagerspetz  and Yu Xiao}, 
        year={2014}, 
        pages={3–22}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    Some text.

    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibi.bib}
    

\end{document}
```